# Flexpaper PDF links opens 2 windows

Tags: hyperlink, flexpaper

Does anyone know how to combat the flexpaper document viewer opening 2 windows when I click on a hyperlink that is contained inside a pdf.

Im creating a viewer online using the standard zine interface for flexpaper. My PDF contains hyperlinks to external websites, when I click these links in the viewer, it opens 2 windows.

I want only 1 window to open.

Any ideas?

Comment: Progress update:

I amended the flexpaper_handlers.js file located in thr js folder. I commented the following function
`code`
jQuery('#documentViewer').bind('onExternalLinkClicked',function(e,link){
        //COMMENTED OUT TO PREVENT DUPLICATE URL WINDOWS OPENING
        //window.open(link,'_flexpaper_exturl');
});`code`

Seems to do the trick for the time being :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in one of our newer releases. Downloading version 2.2.3 or later will fix this without having to comment out any of the javascript.

Comment: This isn't completely fixed. Currently external links on the presentation I'm working on open in the current tab AND a new tab.

Not asking for help here. Just saying it's still an issue, and I saw someone talk about it in 2013 on the help forums as well. Kinda disappointing.